# how to execute parent befor child thread - pthreads in c

Tags: c, pthreads

I want to make it so that parent process executes before the child thread does. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong to get the order my program is outputting.

```
int status = 0;

void *print_child(void *arg)
{

    while (status == 0)
    {
        printf("Signal hasn't changed..\n");
        sleep(1);

    }
    printf("The child has started...\n");
    printf("The child is done! \n ");
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t child;
    pthread_create(&child, NULL, &print_child, NULL);

    sleep(2);
    printf("The parent has started...\n");
    printf("The parent is done! \n");

    status++;

    if (pthread_join(child, NULL))
    {
        printf("ERROR");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
signal has changed
signal has changed
parent has started
parent is done
child has started
child is done
```

Comment: If you want to do actions sequentially, why use threads at all? Threads are for things done in parallel.

Comment: You set parent to sleep while child is running so....

Comment: @DarkFalcon It smell like school assignment

Comment: You can use a condition variable that the child waits on until the parent signals... Even a timed wait... `pthread.h` is full of useful synchronization primitives, you just have to browse through it...

Comment: You can `wait()` for your children, but not for your parent.  You'll need some other form of synchronization.  A pipe can be useful for this.  Worst case, poll until your parent's pid disappears or changes its start time (indicating that it's been recycled).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to exclude concurrent execution is a lock. Have the "parent" (original thread) take a lock before calling `pthread_create`, and only unlock it when it's ready for the "child" (new thread) to to run. The "child" should take the lock before doing anything; it can then unlock it immediately if it wants, or keep it to control access to shared state.